# Redirect domain name mapped with external IP (modem) to a host in its local network

Tags: networking, dns, routes, router

I have a modem that is connected to a router. There are two computers connected to this router. I want to set a domain for one of those computers so that I can access the web deployment server running in that computer from Internet. I used freedns.afraid.org to get a free subdomain. But when I set it up, the domain is getting mapped to my external IP address. So, the problem is that when I try to access the set domain, I am only accessing the modem's configuration page i.e. EXTERNAL_IP:80

In my local network, my modem's IP address is 192.168.0.1 , my router's IP address is 192.168.1.1 and my computers take IP addresses anywhere between 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.148

Also, my router is Linksys WRT54G and is only capable of default DDNS configuration to dyndns and TZO. Since both have become paid services, I opted for free DDNS and I'll use some DDNS update client to update the dynamic IP.

I don't know how to search specifically for this problem in google. Also, I came across port forwarding which was used under similar topics. I am new to this, so can anyone suggest me how to redirect my domain to the particular host or is there any reference page I can learn the procedure from? **SOLVED**

---

**UPDATE ON THE QUESTION (NEW ISSUE)**

Since I didn't have port forwarding option in my modem and also my modem didn't by default forward everything to the router, I had to set up my modem as a bridge to my router. I disabled the modem's DHCP server and enabled only the router's DHCP server. This allowed me to configure port forwarding in the router alone and is working good.

But the problem now is, I am not able to access the modem's configuration page (192.168.1.1). My router is at 192.168.1.2 . Subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 . I tried changing the router to a different subnet say 192.168.0.1, but then the internet connectivity didn't even establish. I tried connecting my computer directly to the modem to access it's configuration page, but that also failed.

Comment: You'll need to configure the NAT settings on the router to forward port 80 to the internal host's IP.  The model will also need to forward everything to the router, which it *should* be doing anyway.  But I can't really speak for the modem.  If it has configuration options available, you can check those.  In any event, the domain is set up correctly (based on the description) to point to your *public* IP.  The device which has that IP needs to forward requests (via NAT configuration) to a *private* IP in your network.

Comment: @David Ok, I checked my router configuration and I have something called Port Forward Range and its description speaks what you said. But I don't find anything like what you said in my modem's configuration. Are all modems equipped with that feature? And also since my router is connected to my modem, I have to obviously enable port forwarding (via NAT) in modem also, right?

Comment: Port Forwarding is what you're looking for, yes.  It should allow you to specify the external port (80), the internal IP (192.168.0.100, for example), the internal port (80), and possibly the protocol (TCP usually).  It makes sense that the modem will also have to forward connections.  But that's up to the modem's configuration.  My cable modem seems to pass through everything to my router, but other modems may operate differently.  If you own the modem, you should have some options to configure it.  (Otherwise you might want to get a different modem.)

Comment: @David Mine is an ADSL modem and it doesn't pass everything to the router and it doesn't support port forwarding either. So, I tried bridging, but came up with another problem which I've updated in this question. Can you check if you can help me solve that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to redirect my domain to the particular host you need to setup **NAT**-*Virtual Server Setup* .

here you need to map remote port to internal map.

[image]

In above image IP address is my IP of my host and Default address is my router's IP address

Now you have configure NAT in you router as bellow.

[image]

in above image server IP is you host IP address.

I am using D-Link router so this Image is according to that if you are using some different router then you might have different view.

After configuring this when you type EXTERNAL_IP:80 your request will be forwarded to application that is running on you host with that port

Comment: Thanks, this also helped me on the port forwarding part. Now, I've updated my question, can you check if you can help me solve that issue?